# change placeholder duration dynamically in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

i'm trying to change external duration on fullcalendar external-dragging example.
https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.2.0/demos/external-dragging.html

the example duration was 02:00:00. but I would like to be changed when drag on calendar.

for example baed on above link, pre-duration of rooms were 02:00:00 and 03:00:00 like "Auditorium A" was 02:00:00 and "Auditorium B" was 03:00:00.

and then, when I drag some external item to calendar. then change the item duration 02:00:00 on "Auditorium A" or 03:00:00 on "Auditorium B".
[image]

```
$(function() { // document ready


    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });


    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        now: '2016-01-07',
        editable: true, // enable draggable events
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
                type: 'timeline',
                duration: { days: 3 }
            }
        },
        resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green', start:"09:00", end:"11:00" },
            { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange', start:"13:30",end:"16:00" }
        ],
        events: [

        ],
        drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
            console.log('drop', date.format(), resourceId);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
            console.log('eventReceive', event);
        },
        eventDrop: function(event) { // called when an event (already on the calendar) is moved
            console.log('eventDrop', event);
        }
    });

});
```

one of above code, there are start/end attribute in resources. so I would like to be applied start/end time when left side external drag on calendar each of rooms.

Comment: Please show your code as well. Where are you storing the desired duration information? Have you made this desired duration an attribute of your resource object?  P.S. 1.2 is a very old version of Scheduler. Latest is 1.9 I think. Consider upgrading for bugfixes, enhancements etc.

Comment: my code is same as above sample. and duration will be stored on each of room like $(".auditoriumE").data("duration","01:30:00"). so I hope when "My Event 1" item of left side, drag to calendar on "auditorium E" 12am. then hope to be determined placeholder from 12am to 2am 30min.

Comment: it would be better stored as a custom attribute of the actual resource JSON object I think, rather than the HTML element. Then it's more structured. P.S. You still need to put _your_ version of the code in here, because clearly you have been making amendments to it. Then it's 100% clear what has changed and what has not.